# Proving $b^{1+n} - c^{1+n} = (b-c)\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{n-k}c^{k}$ using telescoping sums.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was able to prove this using induction, but I'm completely lost in trying to prove it using the fact that $$ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} (c_{k+1} -c_{k}) = c_{n+1} - c_{0}.$$ As of yet, all I've taken note of is that $$(b-c)\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n} b^{n-k}c^{k}= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\big(b^{n-k+1}c^{k}-b^{n-k}c^{k+1}\big),$$ but I'm not sure how to relate this to the telescoping sums above. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\big(b^{n-k+1}c^{k}-b^{n-k}c^{k+1}\big)&=c^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\big(b^{n-k+1}c^{k-n-1}-b^{n-k}c^{k-n}\big)\\
&=c^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\left(\frac bc\right)^{n-(k-1)}-\left(\frac bc\right)^{n-k}\right).
\end{align*}
So we get a telescoping sum and thus
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\big(b^{n-k+1}c^{k}-b^{n-k}c^{k+1}\big)=c^{n+1}\left(\left(\frac bc\right)^{n-(-1)}-\left(\frac bc\right)^{n-n}\right)=b^{n+1}-c^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Clever! Thanks for showing what it means to think outside of the box. I don't think I would have figured that out myself.

Comment: @srvlo You’re welcome. I’m glad to help!